# Iterate over int array

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

Have a question regarding iterarating through int[].
Assume we created int[]:

```
int[] list = new int[5];
```

After we want to populate it. I know it is possible to do it with the next piece of code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < list.length; x++){
        list[x] = x;
}
```

But I really wondering about next one:

```
for(int x : list){
        list[x] = x;
}
```

It does not work and even if I'll put `x++;` in the for-loop body x is 0 every iteration.

I ask not because I won't live without it, I can still use first for-loop for that, but I want to know and use more "new"-"clean"-"better" way, if it's good to say so, to iterate though [].
Thank you in advance.

Comment: in your first loop, the x is an index, in your second loop, the x is the int object itself, therefore list[x] will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always:

```
int[] list = IntStream.range(0, 5).toArray();
```

Comment: @LevanVoronin Note that `rangeClosed(0,5)` will create array for 6 numbers: 0,1,2,3,4,5. If you want to limit it to 5 numbers use `range(0,5)`.

Comment: Or `Arrays.setAll(list, i -> i);`

Comment: @Shmo but `setAll()` won't *create* the array.

Comment: It certainly will not.

Answer (score 0):

in your second version of the loop x isn't an index, it is one the value stored. You cannot change this value from an enhanced for loop because

1. you don't have an index available
2. a enhanced for loop forbid you from modifying the items of the list while you read. While this restriction is mainly a concern for deletion it also it for primitive or immutable types such a String or any primitive wrapper.

Comment: Enhanced for loops don't forbid you from doing anything.

Comment: List<MyClass> l = ...;/*init with items */ 
    for(MyClass c : l){ l.remove(c) } //will shout at you

yes it is not the for loop per se that forbids you but the collection. does it really make a difference in practice?

Comment: Of course it does; not all data structures, or even all lists, have that restriction. And it doesn't apply to arrays, which can't be structurally modified in the first place.

Comment: Yep, I just found it out, thank you so much. I thought x will be like index in `for(int x : list)` but it is element. Thank you for your help. I tried it like `int y = 0;
for(int x : list){
    list[y] = y;
    y++;}`, but it's not clean for sure.

Answer (score -1):

You can't modify an array using an enhanced-for loop. `x` represents each element value, not an index. Therefore `list[x] = x` is likely nonsensical. If you need to modify the elements, use a classic loop with an index variable.

Comment: "You can't modify an array using an enhanced-for loop" isn't true. We can still modify array, but not via `list[x]=x`. If we declare our own iteration counter we can still use `list[iteration++]=newValue;` even inside enhanced-for loop.

Comment: @Pshemo That fact that you can modify an array **while** in an enhanced for loop is completely irrelevant to my point. It's also apparent from the question.

Comment: English is not my native language so I may be misunderstanding you, but do you mean that if execution is *while in* an enhanced for loop then it is not *using* an enhanced-for loop? IMO that is confusing (or at least not obvious) so could you clarified that part of your answer? (BTW, not mine down-vote).

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, that's what I mean. With all due respect, I think additional clarification would only be redundant.